# sed not working on large files. Any other options available?

Tags: unix, sed, text

Trying to insert a line feed on large files in UNIX when a text string matches.  Any file around 1GB or less, it works. Anything over that size, it does not complete the replace. It appears to do nothing.

I'm using the following command:

```
sed -i 's/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}{"active": true/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}\n{"active": true/g' filename.txt
```

I have even tried:

```
sed 's/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}{"active": true/"sourceSystemCode": "xyz"}\n{"active": true/g' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

Any other suggestions to add the line feed using any other command or syntax with sed is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

I see an answer on SO here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388833/sed-not-working-on-large-file-looking-for-other-options

> Perl will let you change the input separator ($/) from newline to
> another character. You could take advantage of this to get some
> convenient chunking.
>
> perl -pe'BEGIN{$/="}"}s/^({"seq_id")/\n$1/' my_giant_json.json That
> sets the input separator to be "}". Then it looks for chunks that
> start with {"seq_id" and prefixes them with a newline.
>
> Note that it puts an unnecessary empty line at the beginning. You
> could complicate the program to eliminate that or just delete it
> manually after.

If you search SO for the first sentence of your question, you'll find a lot of other ideas too.

Comment: I saw that but I don't understand how it works.  That example talks about adding it to the begining of a string.  I'm looking to replace it in the middle of a string.  How would I go about modifying that command to do so.

Comment: just as a trick did you try to ask chatgpt about? ;)